# How do I edit the property file that my osgi managed service implementation uses?

Tags: java, properties, osgi, config

I am using Apache Felix as my OSGi framework implementation. I have a class that is implementing ManagedService in order to get properties from a file using the ConfigAdmin service. I am able to manually edit the properties file and receive updates in my managed service. How do I edit the properties in this file from my managed service? Editing the Dictionary that I get from the update method has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ConfigurationAdmin service has two parts:

1. The ManagedService, a component that *receives* a configuration.
2. The ConfigurationAdmin service, which can be used to *set*, *update* or *delete* a configuration.

In other words, if you want to change your own configuration, you need to talk to the ConfigurationAdmin service to do that.

By the way, nowhere in the spec does it say that there is a "file" holding the configuration. It is up to ConfigurationAdmin to decide how to persist (in a file, database, whatever). All management of configurations goes through the ConfigurationAdmin service.

Comment: Thanks. Editing the properties using the Configuration object worked. I just had to handle a bundle start order issue.